# Find best matches of substring from list in corpus

Tags: python, nlp, match, levenshtein-distance

I have a corpus that looks something like this

> LETTER AGREEMENT N°5 CHINA SOUTHERN AIRLINES COMPANY LIMITED Bai Yun
> Airport, Guangzhou 510405, People's Republic of China Subject: Delays
> CHINA SOUTHERN AIRLINES COMPANY LIMITED (the ""Buyer"") and AIRBUS
> S.A.S. (the ""Seller"") have entered into a purchase agreement (the
> ""Agreement"") dated as of even date

And a list of company names that looks like this

```
l = [ 'airbus', 'airbus internal', 'china southern airlines', ... ]
```

The elements of this list do not always have exact matches in the corpus, because of different formulations or just typos: for this reason I want to perform fuzzy matching.

What is the most efficient way of finding the best matches of `l` in the corpus? In theory the task is not super difficult but I don't see a way of solving it that does not entail looping through both the corpus and list of matches, which could cause huge slowdowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate your list `l` in a single regex expression, then use [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) to fuzzy match (https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex#approximate-fuzzy-matching-hg-issue-12-hg-issue-41-hg-issue-109) the words in the corpus.

Something like

```py
my_regex = ""
for pattern in l:
    my_regex += f'(?:{pattern}' + '{1<=e<=3})' #{1<=e<=3} permit at least 1 and at most 3 errors
    my_regex += '|'
my_regex = my_regex[:-1] #remove the last |
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution to explore for sure! However I have some doubts: company names tend to have typos, deletion or legal suffixes. I have the feeling it would be too hard to try to specify a fuzzy matching rules in regex for all these cases. Furthermore, is there any way to get a numeric score for the match like with the distance?

Comment: Yes, look at the documentation I linked, you can have the number of substitutions, insertions and deletions.